# How to quickly copy the whole Excel to another Excel as value

Tags: excel

How to quickly copy a whole Excel spread-sheet to another Excel spread-sheet by value? And how to quickly copy some sheets of an Excel spread-sheet to another Excel spread-sheet by value? Without using VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).

For example: suppose I have a spread-sheet called Excel_A with several sheets and with lots of formulas. I want to quickly copy all of Excel_A's values. I want to avoid copying sheet by sheet into another spread-sheet because it will be too slow and there are a lot of sheets in Excel_A.

Comment: What you mean by value? ignoring formula and copy pasting only the values?

Comment: Please expand this question a lot more to enable people to help you.

Comment: @GowthamShiva yes,  copy pasting only the values

Comment: @JoshFriedlander pls see the update.

Comment: It sounds like you would like to loop through each sheet in WorkBook A, copy everything in it, and paste as values in a sheet in workbook B. Does this sound right?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander just want to get a Excel_B same as Excel_A but totally passing by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, dirty workaround, not involving code (which you don't seem inclined to write) is the following:

1. Save Excel_A As Excel_B
2. Right-click on one of the sheet handles at the bottom, and click Select All Sheets.

[image]

3. Ctrl-A to Select All, Ctrl-C to copy, Alt E-S-V and Enter to paste values.

Alternatively, it's definitely doable with VBA too. Something similar to the below ought to work. (It assumes both workbooks are open, otherwise replace the names with addresses.)

```
Sub CopyValuesToNewBook()

    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Set wbA = Workbooks("Excel_A")
    Dim wbB As Workbook
    Set wbTest = Workbooks("Excel_B")

    For Each Sheet In wbA.Sheets
        Sheet.Copy
        Dim IndexNo As Integer
        IndexNo = Sheets(Sheet).Index
        wbB.Sheets(IndexNo).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @A.Oreo did you have a try with my answer?

Comment: @GowthamShiva yeah, but the result is not I want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple approach that you could follow,

Copy the ranges that you want to copy-paste. Open a new text document and paste it in the txt document. CTRL+A (select all) in the txt file, copy everything and then paste it in the required excel sheet. This would eliminate all the formulas in the cells and would copy just the values in the cell.

If you want to copy the entire sheet, select all (CTRL+A) in that sheet and do the same. You will not be able to copy-paste sheet using the normal way. This can be done sheet by sheet only unless you develop a macro or something else. Hope this helps